# Using 5.1 surround to play back 3 independent stereo streams

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, speakers, alsa

I built a small home server recently. It runs Ubuntu Server 12.04 and has a sound card (Via VT1708) with 3 audio jacks - which I want to use as 3 independent stereo outputs to play back (potentially different) audio in different parts of my home. To do this, I am mixing all application audio into a 6-channel stream; this stream has 2 channels of target audio for each location playback should be possible in.

Each jack should then output one of the stereo streams *independently of the other channels*. Herein lies the problem.

I have managed to play back a 6-channel audio file almost exactly in the desired way. I am using [this file](http://www.jensign.com/bdp95/7dot1voiced/) (the 5.1/6-channel version) for testing the 'isolation' of every channel. On a different computer, the output worked as expected: when playing back the test file, I'd hear one number exclusively on one of the 6 speakers. I wasn't so lucky on the target machine, though.

Sound is played on speakers connected to all three jacks. However, the sound from the rear left/right channels is also heard on the front left/right channels respectively, although slightly quieter.

I have been trying to go from there, but without any success. I would be thankful for any pointers on how to proceed, what to test, etc.

Some (hopefully) useful console outputs with system details:

**$ aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: VT82xx [HDA VIA VT82xx], device 0: VT1708 Analog [VT1708 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: VT82xx [HDA VIA VT82xx], device 1: VT1708 Digital [VT1708 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**$ cat /proc/asound/cards**

```
 0 [VT82xx         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA VIA VT82xx
                      HDA VIA VT82xx at 0xfebfc000 irq 17
```

**$ lsmod | grep snd**

```
snd_hda_codec_via      23198  1 
snd_hda_intel          43326  1 
snd_hda_codec         169608  2 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94597  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25157  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                55716  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28930  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    61270  12 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12600  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18398  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

My ~/.asoundrc is empty.

Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Try `speaker-test` with device `hw`. What is the output of `amixer scontents`?

Comment: @CL. Sorry, was out of town for a week for a personal emergency. `speaker-test` yielded the same result as described in the question (not full channel isolation; rear channels are bleeding through to the front ones). As soon as I can, I will post the output you requested (can't access the system for the next 24 hours).